# How to change the default Pod address in openshift origin?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I am using Openshift Origin to setup a lab environment. But after doing openshift-ansible, it seems the default Pod address are 10.1.x.x . It conflicts with my company intranet address.

So how to change the default Pod address?

```
[root@openshiftorigin-master ~]# netstat -ar
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens32
10.1.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 tun0
172.16.50.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens32
172.30.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 tun0
```

Thanks,
James.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pods are given addresses out of the ClusterNetworkCIDR in the master config.  You will need to restart all pods after changing this value (the documentation describes other implications of changing this value on a running cluster).